# Override Spring Security autoconfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have an jar with a own spring security filter and my own security configuration.
This jar is called from a Spring Boot application and I would like disable the spring boot security configuration (without excludes or properties) and put my spring security configuration (this jar is in spring 4.X). How can I build an autoconfiguration for my Spring Security,and  override the autoconfiguration of Spring Boot by default?:

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: My first step have been disable the spring security filter chain with a class that implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, and I'm not sure Which can be our next step.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have created my own auto-configuration, an class @autoconfiguration with an @conditionalonmissingclass and an import of my security.